# addcslashes(), charlist parameter - Is the explanation on php.net correct?

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3, addslashes

When I run this piece of code:

```
echo addcslashes('testing\n', "\n");
```

It outputs this:

```
"testing\n"
```

The explanation of Parameters -> `Charlist` says:

> If `charlist` contains characters \n, \r etc., they are converted into `C-like` style

but this does not seem to be correct. This would mean that `"\n"` gets converted to `"\n"` in C-like style which would not be making any sense.

So can it be stated that php.net page is not correct? Would it be correct if it would be saying that these types of characters just stay the same? I am learning the PHP programming and I want to make sure that the info that I have is correct.

Comment: `'\n'` from the first string is not the same as `"\n"` from the second. The first is two bytes and two ASCII characters, the second is one byte and one ASCII character.

Comment: What other words could be used for "converted in C-like style"? What would be the best explanation of that? This is here, at Parameters -> Charlist http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php

Comment: echo addcslashes("testing\n", "\n"); - how many bytes and ASCII characters this would have (in double quotes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that a `\n` (inside double quotes) will be escaped and becomes `\\n`:

```
var_dump("testing\n"); // 8 bytes
var_dump(addcslashes("testing\n", "\n")); // 9 bytes
```

Will outputs:

```
string(8) "testing
"
string(9) "testing\n"
```